# Calcular valor según selección

Tags: php

me han solicitado lo siguiente:

Calcular costo de servicios en función de

1. Cantidad de Guardias requeridos
2. Turno del guardia (Diurno/Nocturno/Tiempo completo)
3. Cada turno tiene un valor diferente, es decir, Diurno cuesta 100$, nocturno 200$, todo el dia $300 (son valores de ejemplo).

Resultado: Costo total de lo requerido.

Soy nuevo y quisiera saber que me recomienda para realizarlo, alguna manera en específica ?

Comment: Hay mil maneras de hacer esto, pero en la pregunta no es claro si quieres por ejemplo calcular un costo basado en varios valores (varios guardias varios turnos), o si quieres calcular el costo de `n` guardias en el turno `x`, etc. Ya que no muestras ningún esfuerzo de solución (quizá porque no sabes por dónde empezar), al menos sé claro planteando el problema.

Comment: Vale, estás en lo correcto honestamente no se como empezar, lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

Entras al formulario, introduces cuantos guardias necesitas, seleccionas el turno en el cual requieres dichos guardias y le das calcular costo y arroje el resultado en dólares estadounidenses.

Cada turno tiene un costo diferente por lo que si eligen 2 guardias en diurno ejemplo, deberá multiplicar la cantidad de guardias (2) por 100USD$ y arrojar el resultado = Costo por servicio de guardia Diurno: 200USD$